# Twitter API. How to get metadata ONLY

Tags: json, twitter

**TL;DR How to limit Twitter API search to search_metadata only?**

Hello everyone, I am writing a program for ESP8266 wifi module. And the problem is - it has very limited resources.

In my program, I need to count a number of tweets containing certain hashtag in the past 24 hours. Normally, this would be the very easy thing to do, because Twitter API already provides this data in json responses.

Example: (look for search_metadata->count at the very bottom of the page)
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/api-reference/get-search-tweets.html

But as you can see json for a single tweet contains a massive amount of data. And I cannot store it on my ESP8266 controller (at max I could store and process data for only 2 tweets at any given time).

So yeah, is there any way to limit Twitter API search, so I would only get search_metadata and nothing else?

Comment: There's no way to do this with the standard search API. The premium 30 day search API has a count endpoint so you can just get result counts in a time period.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks!